# How to make UIBezierPath to fill from the center

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

How do I make a UIBezierPath that starts drawing from the center and expands to the left and right?

My current solution is not using UIBezierPath but rather a UIView inside another UIView. The children view is centered inside of it's parent and I adjust child's width when I need it to expand. However, this solution is far from perfect because the view is located inside of UIStackView and the stack view is in   UICollectionView cell and it sometimes does not get the width correctly.

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    progressView.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    clipsToBounds = true
    addSubview(progressView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        progressView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        progressView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        progressView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor)
    ])
    let width = frame.width
    let finalProgress = CGFloat(progress) * width
    let widthConstraint = progressView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: finalProgress)
    widthConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
    widthConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

the progress is a class property of type double and when it gets set I call layoutIfNeeded.

I also tried calling setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded but it does not solve the issue. SetNeedsDisplay and invalidateIntrinzicSize do not work either.

Now, I would like to do it using bezier path, but the issue is that it starts from a given point and draws from left to right. The question is: how do I make a UIBezierPath that is centered and when I increase the width it expands (stays in center)

Here is the image of what I want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: Nevertheless the way I would do this is just what you said at first, a view that draws a horizontal shape in its own width.

Comment: The problem is that after scrolling a couple of times, it stops updating or for some reason gets it incorrectly because it does not call layoutSubviews every time. I tried forcing layoutSubviews but it does not work.

Comment: That would be for some other reason that you have not revealed in your question. "after scrolling a couple of times" suggests that you are not taking cell reuse into account. But it's hard to say, because you have not shown the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few options. But here are a few:

1. `CABasicAnimation` of the `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` of `CAShapeLayer`, namely:

   - Create `CAShapeLayer` whose `path` is the final `UIBezierPath` (full width), but whose `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` are both 0.5 (i.e. start half-way, and finish half-way, i.e. nothing visible yet).

     ```
     func configure() {
         shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
         shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
         setProgress(0, animated: false)
     }

     func updatePath() {
         let path = UIBezierPath()
         path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + lineWidth, y: bounds.midY))
         path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX - lineWidth, y: bounds.midY))
         shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
         shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
     }
     ```
   - Then, in `CABasicAnimation` animate the change of the `strokeStart` to `0` and the `strokeEnd` to `1` to achieve the animation growing both left and right from the middle. For example:

     ```
     func setProgress(_ progress: CGFloat, animated: Bool = true) {
         let percent = max(0, min(1, progress))
         let strokeStart = (1 - percent) / 2
         let strokeEnd = 1 - (1 - percent) / 2

         if animated {
             let strokeStartAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
             strokeStartAnimation.fromValue = shapeLayer.strokeStart
             strokeStartAnimation.toValue = strokeStart

             let strokeEndAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
             strokeEndAnimation.fromValue = shapeLayer.strokeEnd
             strokeEndAnimation.toValue = strokeEnd

             let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
             animation.animations = [strokeStartAnimation, strokeEndAnimation]

             shapeLayer.strokeStart = strokeStart
             shapeLayer.strokeEnd = strokeEnd

             layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
         } else {
             shapeLayer.strokeStart = strokeStart
             shapeLayer.strokeEnd = strokeEnd
         }
     }
     ```
2. Animation of the `path` of a `CAShapeLayer`

   - Have method that creates the `UIBezierPath`:

     ```
     func setProgress(_ progress: CGFloat, animated: Bool = true) {
         self.progress = progress

         let cgPath = path(for: progress).cgPath

         if animated {
             let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
             animation.fromValue = shapeLayer.path
             animation.toValue = cgPath

             shapeLayer.path = cgPath

             layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
         } else {
             shapeLayer.path = cgPath
         }
     }
     ```

     Where

     ```
     func path(for progress: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
         let path = UIBezierPath()
         let percent = max(0, min(1, progress))
         let width = bounds.width - lineWidth
         path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX - width * percent / 2 , y: bounds.midY))
         path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX + width * percent / 2, y: bounds.midY))
         return path
     }
     ```
   - When you create the `CAShapeLayer` call `setProgress` with value of `0` and no animation; and
   - When you want to animate it out, then call `setProgress` with value of `1` but with animation.
3. Abandon `UIBezierPath`/`CAShapeLayer` approaches and use `UIView` and `UIView` block-based animation:

   - Create short `UIView` with a `backgroundColor` and whose layer has a `cornerRadius` which is half the height of the view.
   - Define constraints such that the view has a zero width. E.g. you might define the `centerXanchor` and so that it’s placed where you want it, and with a `widthAnchor` is zero.
   - Animate the constraints by setting the existing `widthAnchor`’s `constant` to whatever width you want and place `layoutIfNeeded` inside a `UIView` animation block.